# UWP IoT - simplest way to get outlook.com calendars

Tags: c#, outlook, calendar, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

Currently i'm trying to get calendars from two different accounts in my UWP app on my raspberry pi IoT. My goal is to display recent Events from different users in my home (multiple Microsoft account calendars). Currently i don't know where to start and which is the simplest way to achieve this.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok now i have a solution for my problem. Since with the Graph API, only one account can be logged in at the same time, i made a new MS Account and imported shared read only calendars, from other persons MS Accounts. Now i can use the Graph API to Access and read all These calendars without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for the Microsoft Graph API: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/calendar

Comment: With Microsoft Graph it is also possible to access calendars from different users (Microsoft accounts) at the same time?

Comment: Ok tested it, with Microsoft Graph API, i can only read calendars from one user. There would be the possibility to share other calendars and add it to one user, but this is not the idea. So is there any other possibility, to access calendars from different users?

Comment: you can do with a app account; url will look like https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<upn>/calendars/<nameofcalandar>/events

Comment: What is an app account?